# How to make emacs quit the minibuffer with one press of ESC?

Tags: emacs

I often press the wrong combination of keys and open some obscure minibuffer mode. I have to press ESC three times (I think), which is pretty annoying. How do I make emacs quit the minibuffer with just one press of ESC?

Comment: `C-g` should default to `abort-recursive-edit` which will exit the minibuffer, unless you have another `recursive-edit` active.  You could also write your own function using `top-level` which aborts all levels of `recursive-edit` and exits the minibuffer.  I like a custom function written by Stefan which lets me control the escape key to use it as both a modifier key and also as a key that works with just one press:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20026083/how-to-use-escape-conditionally-as-a-modifier-key

Comment: Can this be moved to SO so that I can place a bounty on the question and get some usable elisp?

Comment: Here is something like what you are seeking, but it is **not** recommended.  You can always comment it out later if you decide you want the default behavior:  `(global-set-key (kbd "<escape>") 'top-level) (define-key minibuffer-local-map "<escape>" 'top-level) (define-key minibuffer-local-ns-map "<escape>" 'top-level) (define-key minibuffer-local-completion-map "<escape>" 'top-level) (define-key minibuffer-local-must-match-map "<escape>" 'top-level) (define-key minibuffer-local-isearch-map "<escape>" 'top-level)`  My recommendation, however, is to use the function written by Stefan (above).

Answer (score 3):

Thanks for all your ideas. Seems like this should do the trick:

`(define-key minibuffer-local-map (kbd "ESC") 'keyboard-escape-quit)`

It only worked for isearch. Seems like I'd have to rebind it for every single function (smex, ibuffer, and all those other that uses the minibuffer).

Answer (score 2):

I believe that [ergoemacs](http://ergoemacs.org/) uses the `ESC` key the way you want. It also changes lots of other Emacs key bindings - but probably in ways that agree with your desire to "avoid long emacsy keypresses".

[***Caveat:***
I am no expert on ergoemacs, and I do **not** recommend using `ESC` that way. `ESC` has a particular role in Emacs wrt the `Meta` modifier and keymaps, and treating it otherwise is asking for trouble sooner or later.
(Similarly, `C-g` is fundamental to Emacs, and is even hard-coded in some cases, so it is not 100% replaceable by another key.)]

Answer (score 1):

I usually use the following key combination: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>X</kbd> (enter command-mode) <kbd>K</kbd> (Kill), then <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

This should kill the current mini-buffer.

Comment: Thanks, but I am looking to avoid long emacsy keypresses. That is one more keypress than I currently use (ESC ESC ESC); I'd just like to press ESC once to exit the minibuffer.

Answer (score 0):

I wanna do similar thing: press ESC to cancel the save-buffers-kill-terminal function during the "Save file" prompt.

I tried to rebind ESC in many minibuffer keymaps as mentioned in [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757612/how-to-redefine-a-key-inside-a-minibuffer-mode-map).  However, I still cannot cancel the "Save file" prompt by ESC.

After digging some elisp source codes, I found that query-replace-map is the keymap-parent of map-y-or-n-p, which is used by save-buffers-kill-terminal.  So my final fix is:

```
(define-key query-replace-map (kbd "<escape>") 'keyboard-quit)
```

Note that it disables all shortcuts with meta key.

Answer (score 0):

What you probably want is to use `minibuffer-setup-hook` to bind ESC in every minibuffer's local map.

```
(add-hook 'minibuffer-setup-hook (lambda ()
    (local-set-key (kbd "ESC") 'abort-minibuffers))
```

Since this uses the local key map for each mini buffer, you don't have to rebind it for each command's keymap - the local map will usually get precedence over whatever that minibuffer command is doing.